# NetTcpBinding problems

Tags: c#, network-programming

I have created a windows service with the following code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var localAddress = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost");
    var netExposedAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:8523");

    var addressCollection = new Uri[] { localAddress, netExposedAddress };
    var type = typeof(AnalCron);

    host = new ServiceHost(type, addressCollection);

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAnalCron),
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
    "PipeReverse");

    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IAnalCron),
    new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None),
    "TcpReverse");

    host.Open();

    TheLoop();
}
```

and I have written tests to see if I can communicate with the service when it gets deployed:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestRemote()
{
    var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
    var epAddrs = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://192.168.201.27:8523/TcpReverse");

    var pipeFactory =
      new ChannelFactory<IAnalCron>(
        binding,
        epAddrs);

    IAnalCron pipeProxy =
    pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

    var x = pipeProxy.ReverseString("bla");

    Assert.AreEqual("alb", x);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestLocal()
{
    var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
    var epAddrs = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse");

    var pipeFactory =
      new ChannelFactory<IAnalCron>(
        binding,
        epAddrs);

    IAnalCron pipeProxy =
      pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

    var x = pipeProxy.ReverseString("bla");

    Assert.AreEqual("alb", x);
}
```

when I use the service from my local machine no problems arise but when I use the above code to access a remote machine on the network i get the following error:

> Could not connect to net.tcp://192.168.201.27:8523/TcpReverse. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:21.0231021. TCP
>   error code 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   192.168.201.27:8523.

I have tried to enter the machine name instead of the IP address but no luck. There is no configuration in the .config file, I would like to set everything in code. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could be blocked by the firewall, are the ports open?

Comment: @stuartd thank you, it was a firewall problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @stuartd pointed out, i had problems with my firewall configuration. When i added the service to the exception list communication went on without a hitch.